# Does Android Webview support Spdy V3?

Tags: android, networking, webview, spdy

I am developping Hybrid App with Html5 page loaded by Webview, So I wonder if SPDY/3 is enabled default(Android 4.X).

I have heard that Android Browser since Honeycomb supports SPDY/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome for Android and [Chrome Webview for Android](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview) both support SPDY.

Old Webview does not have SPDY support. If you do want, or need to, use SPDY on older Android platforms (Chrome powered Webview is 4.4+), you can use a native java implementation and integrate that into your app - e.g. [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library.